# are window unit ACs supposed to let in air when turned off?

Tags: insulation, air-conditioning

I live in an ancient building in a large, old city. I just replaced two decades-old window ACs that came with the place, and the new units let in air. Before I added insulation, when it got cold outside, it got cold inside.

There is surprisingly little information about this issue on the web, or I am surprisingly bad at search. Some resources claim that window units aren't supposed to let in outside air, unless there's a vent control. (One of my 2 new units has a vent control, labeled 'closed | exhaust | open', the other does not. Both leak air).

There are a lot of tools for winterizing *around* the unit, like breeze stopper or frost king, but relatively few for insulating the unit itself. (The 2 I've tried, an elastic-band quilt and a rigid bucket called chill stop'r, didn't fit well enough to solve the problem).

My next step is to custom-fabricate an insulated cover for the worst offender of the two units, but I'm very surprised there isn't more info about this problem online. Are window AC units supposed to let in air when turned off?

Comment: the shouldn't let air in even when running

Comment: They are obviously not _supposed to_. Your insulated cover is the best solution short of replacing the unit, or removing the unit seasonally(PITA).

Comment: They’re not completely airtight. For example, condensing water runs down off the evaporator (cold side) and needs to flow down and out to the warm side. That’s enough to feel a draft. And if you find the vent itself, it’s probably a thin plastic cover without a gasket.